# Multiple entry-points in webpack with react-router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am facing tremendous issues trying to implement multiple entry points along with react router. The aim is to achieve using webpack to do something that is suggested by https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto.

So far I have currently set it up like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry: {
    entry1: __dirname + './entry1.jsx',
    entry2: __dirname + './entry2.jsx'
}
```

**routes.jsx**

```
export default (
   <Route path='/' name='app' handler={App}>
      <DefaultRoute handler={entry1} />
      <Route name='entry2' handler={entry2}/>
   </Route>
);
```

Whenever this code is run to instantiate a instance of **Router** on the client

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, (Handler, state) => {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Node.js will try to run this code on the server which obviously fails as DOM is not available there. It will produce an error.

Is there any proper way to implement multiple-entry points with react-router?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similiar to this in a sandbox [webpack-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mderrick/webpack-react-boilerplate) repository I've been playing around with using react-router.

I believe the answer you may be looking for lies [here](https://github.com/mderrick/webpack-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/server.js#L14) where you need to use `React.renderToString` and/or `React.renderToStaticMarkup` in your server entry file as you rightly suggest, there is obviously no DOM on the server. You can see how the client entry point [here](https://github.com/mderrick/webpack-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/client.js#L8) differs to the server one.